# cin a very big int array, segment fault 11

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    std::cin>>n;
    int lh[n][2];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin>>lh[i][0]>>lh[i][1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why, if n is very small, it runs ok, but when n is bigger, say 10,000,000, it turns out a `segmentfault 11` error.

What's going on here ?

Comment: You probably cannot fit 80,000,000 bytes on the stack (160,000,000 bytes if `int` is 64-bits wide on your platform). Use dynamic memory instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you REALLY want to use a raw array, you have to allocate it dynamically, i.e. on heap:

```
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    std::cin>>n;
    int** lh = new int[n][2];

    // Allocate memory
    lh = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        lh[i] = new int[2];

    // Assign values
    lh[0][0] = 3;
    lh[1][2] = 4;

    // De-Allocate memory to prevent memory leak
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        delete [] lh[i];
    delete [] lh;
    return 0;
}
```

However, as you're presumably not ready for multi-dimensional raw heap arrays yet, I strongly advise you to use `std::vector` and smaller array size instead:

```
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    std::cin>>n;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > myVec;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        std::vector<int> tempV;
        int input = 0;
        cin >> input;
        tempV.push_back(input);
        cin >> input;
        tempV.push_back(input);

        myVec.push_back(std::move(tempV));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or to keep the order, `std::vector< std::array<int,2> > myVec;`

Comment: In most cases, I prefer vector. In this case too, unless the author has some very good reasons for raw arrays. Besides, it would be allocated on stack.

Comment: The 'vector' itself is always on the stack, but they're just a handful of bytes. The memory a vector uses to hold the contents is *never* on the stack.

Comment: I found this step `lh[i] = new int[2];` is pretty slow, is there any way to allocate the memory one time ?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly this is not valid C++.

```
std::cin>>n;
int lh[n][2];
```

n should be a compile time constant.

Secondly as already pointed out, you are using too much memory for large n

Comment: How do I allocate the `lh` in heap ? Haven't use C++ for a very long time.

Comment: Note that `gcc` and `clang` support `VLA` as an extension in *C++*.

Comment: @MrROY See this link. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21909/Introduction-to-dynamic-two-dimensional-arrays-in

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes I'm aware that some compilers allow VLA in C++, however AFAIK as per standard it is not allowed 'as yet'.

Answer (score 1):

It is funny, but it is exactly 'stack overflow'. 
When you say 'int x[n]', the memory for array x allocated on the stack. The default stack size is depend on OS, but in any case it is some concrete number (let say 8M). When n is big enough, stack overflow occurs. To avoid this effect, allocate memory on heap. I.e.

```
int *x = new int[n];
```

Comment: Is there any `new int[n][2]` in C++ ?

Comment: I also was surprised, but gcc 4.7 allows it (i checked). May be part of c++-11?

Comment: @BorisT: It might become part of C++14, unfortunately. But in your case, no, it's a GCC extension that I've found to be wholly unreliable. There are also cases in which the code will be accepted with the extension turned off, producing unexpected results at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

couple of cases here : 10,000,000 is probably outside the range of an integer datatype in your platform. In your code both `i` and `n` are integers.
Again you might not be able to allocate that much space on the stack (again depends on the platform).

Comment: But who uses 16-bit ints nowadays?